# SMPS transformer selection

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

I am trying to find a transformer for my Switched-Mode Power Supply (Full-bridge LLC series resonant converter) circuit which transforms 700 VDC to 70 VDC in a frequency of 300 kHz for a 10KW application.
Is there any transformer like this in the market?
If not, how can I make that using other transformers?

Comment: What type of SMPS topology does it use? If you don't know and you don't have a schematic then this becomes guesswork and, given the voltages and powers mentioned, nobody should guess.

Comment: You have to custom wind it. You will not find any off the shelf part for that.

Comment: @Andyaka It is a Full-bridge LLC series resonant converter.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally the practice in engineering with a requirement like you have to prepare a detailed specification of the transformer needed. Then you take that specification to several transformer manufacturers to get quotes on R&D sample plus production part costs. Then using the results of the quotation process you select one manufacturer and get them to build your first prototype transformer.

Note that it is often the case that your idea for the specification of the transformer does not match exactly with the way the selected manufacture can build the part. You then will have to work with them to adjust the specification. Some of the items that may come into play:

1. Core material
2. Physical size
3. Agency approvals
4. Lead termination style
5. Mounting style
6. Amount and type of testing they will perform
7. High voltage rating
8. Temperature rating
9. Efficiency
10. Primary winding impedance (AC and DC)
11. Secondary winding impedance (AC and DC)

I would rather doubt that you would easily find a ready made transformer to suit your application.